# validate cloudpage data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sql, cloudpage

I'm very much stuck on how to approach this, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

**Background**
A client wants to build a simple cloudpage from which entities will fill in their details, and submit this data into SFMC. One of the fields that needs to be submitted is policy_number.

Despite this field already existing in SFMC, entities need to manually submit this via the cloudpage because they are not being sent to the form via email - so I can't do a Lookup. This is not ideal, and I'm tempted to challenge the client on this.

**Problem**
Once the entity has submitted this data, I need to check that the policy_number they input matches what we have in SFMC. If it doesn't, it should be overwritten with the correct policy_number. This is essential as the entity may input the wrong number.

How can I do this? I believe that if the entities were sent the cloudpage via email, I can simply pass through their details with ampscript, and do a lookup to validate their information.

Comment: How does the recipient have the Cloudpage URL?

Comment: It will be posted on an internal webpage.

Comment: How can you identify the relationship between the correct policy_number and the entity?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create an additional handler page (also a Cloudpage) to check and progress data.

In the main Cloudpage: put handler page URL in the "form action" with the POST method so it can wrap the form response and send it to the handler page.

In the handler page:

1. [RequestParameter](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/) to get all the field values including the policy_number field.
2. Use 1 or multiple fields you get from step 1 as the identifiers for the lookup to your stored DE for the policy_number value.

E.g.

```
%%[
set @policy_number = Lookup("Your policy DE","policy_number","EmailAddress", @Email, "FirstName", @fName)
]%%
```

3. Do the next thing you want to do after that. E.g. upsert to an DE

Comment: Unless you are passing additional parameters to the processing page (handler page) then you don't need to use CloudPagesURL as the form POST would properly secure the responses. I mention this because at times I have seen issues with form posts when using CloudPagesURL where the fields do not come through, or come through with unexpected results.

Comment: @Gortonington Ahh you are right; there is no need to use CloudPagesURL. Specifying the POST method in the form is a better choice. I was afraid that data would be showed in URL so I used this function. Thank you for your insights!